# How to display a matrix in the Matplotlib annotations

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a matrix using the annotations of a Matplotlib-Plot. Is this even possible?

Tried around with the most basic example, which all break the plot:

```
ax.annotate(r"$ \begin{matrix} a & b & c \\
              d & e & f \\ 
              g & h & i \end{matrix} $", (0.25, 0.25),
              textcoords='axes fraction', size=20)
```

#### Edit:

Part of the problem was that I was missing "texlive-latex-extra" which contains "type1cm", which is needed to render this correctly. See also: [Python: Unable to Render Tex in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/python-unable-to-render-tex-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MatPlotLib uses its own typesetting framework ([MathText](http://matplotlib.org/api/mathtext_api.html)). Your system's LaTeX rendering can be enabled by, `rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`.

The other problem that you have is a double-quoted multi-line string. This isn't really allowed without using a `\`, and that is difficult to manage with your existing `\\`.

Try this:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

ax.annotate(
    r"$ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} $",
    (0.25, 0.25),
    textcoords='axes fraction', size=20)
```

Here I have used the `array` environment, rather than `matrix` because I don't think the latter is a LaTeX built-in. If you really want `matrix`--or other amsmath items--you can add the amsmath package to the MatPlotLib LaTeX preamble:

```
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
```

Then the `matrix` environment will work,

```
ax.annotate(
    r"$ \begin{matrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{matrix} $",
    (0.25, 0.25),
    textcoords='axes fraction', size=20)
```

Comment: It seems like there is a bug in the current 1.5 build of matplotlib, because I can't get either of the two solutions to work.

Comment: Do you have LaTeX installed on your system?

Comment: I have no idea how you guessed that, but you are right. I edited the question to what solved the problem. I am now using your first suggestion which looks exactly like what I wanted to do. Thank you again!