# Add matrix in X-axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I try to add matrices in X-axis using matplotlib. 
The code I wrote is:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import numpy as np
import math
import decimal 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab 
from matplotlib import rcParams

def plot():           
    N = 6
    ind = np.arange(N)
    ind_label = ['1X', '2X' , '3X' , '4X', '5X', '6X']

    y = [1.60, 1.65, 1.70, 1.75, 1.80]
    m1 = [1.62, 1.64, 1.64, 1.71, 1.7, 1.68]
    m2 = [1.61 , 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.75, 1.75]
    m3 = [1.63 , 1.69, 1.7, 1.67, 1.64, 1.61]

    width = 0.2

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    rec_m1 = ax.bar(ind, m1, width, color='r', align='center')
    rec_m2 = ax.bar(ind+width, m2, width, color='g', align='center')
    rec_m3 = ax.bar(ind+width*2, m3, width, color='b', align='center')

    ax.set_ylabel('Value',fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('Matrix', fontsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=17)
    ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ind_label, fontsize=18)
    ax.axis([-0.2, 5.6, 1.58, 1.82])

    ax.legend((rec_m1[0],rec_m2[0],rec_m3[0]),('Method 1','Method 2','Method 3'), loc="upper right",shadow=True)

    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot()
```

The current output figure is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJVxA.png

However, the most painful part is to add X-labels. 
I show the expected output in the figure. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6h3U.png

I tried the method mentioned in this post [How to display a matrix in the Matplotlib annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329177/how-to-display-a-matrix-in-the-matplotlib-annotations) .

But it does not work in my case. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there; with the links provided in your question, you can solve it as follows:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                    r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 5 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                    r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 10 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                    r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 30 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                    r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 50 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                    r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 100 & 0 \end{array}\right]$"])
```

The total code becomes:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import numpy as np
import math
import decimal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from matplotlib import rcParams

def plot():
    N = 6
    ind = np.arange(N)
    ind_label = ['1X', '2X' , '3X' , '4X', '5X', '6X']

    y = [1.60, 1.65, 1.70, 1.75, 1.80]
    m1 = [1.62, 1.64, 1.64, 1.71, 1.7, 1.68]
    m2 = [1.61 , 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.75, 1.75]
    m3 = [1.63 , 1.69, 1.7, 1.67, 1.64, 1.61]

    width = 0.2

    rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    rec_m1 = ax.bar(ind, m1, width, color='r', align='center')
    rec_m2 = ax.bar(ind+width, m2, width, color='g', align='center')
    rec_m3 = ax.bar(ind+width*2, m3, width, color='b', align='center')

    ax.set_ylabel('Value',fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('Matrix', fontsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=17)
    ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ind_label, fontsize=18)
    ax.axis([-0.2, 5.6, 1.58, 1.82])

    ax.legend((rec_m1[0],rec_m2[0],rec_m3[0]),('Method 1','Method 2','Method 3'), loc="upper right",\
shadow=True)
    ax.set_xticklabels([r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                        r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 5 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                        r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 10 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                        r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 30 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                        r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 50 & 0 \end{array}\right]$",
                        r"$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 100 & 0 \end{array}\right]$"])
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=15)

    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot()
```

A few notes:

- You will require LaTeX on your system.
- This can take a while to render: this is because Matplotlib was developed to create high quality plots, plus the additional LaTeX rendering underneath for each label.
- I have offset the tick labels using `xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=15)`, because with the brackets around the matrix, the tick labels ended up inside the plot
- They are probably ways (e.g. using more `rcParams`) to change the font size or the used LaTeX font.

The resulting figure is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help. Actually, some of my setting is wrong. And I got this error: `raise ValueError: left cannot be >= right` and `raise ValueError('bottom cannot be >= top')`... If I change to another host, then your code works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Neverfaraway I wouldn't know about the error, but perhaps that host has an older version of numpy or matplotlib that's causing problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I upgrade the numpy and matplotlib on my host, but the error is still there. It is so weird. I reported this issue at Matplotlib@Github. Hope they can have some insights on this error. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can also put the error as a question on SO. If you do so, *do* include the full traceback, so people can see where the error occurs. Include a small program that causes the error, and don't forget to identify your platform/OS in the question as well.