# How to render a latex matrix by using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to render a latex matrix by using matplotlib.

this latex string works well by its own

```
$\begin{bmatrix}    A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\    A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$
```

which generates a matrix as expected.

[image]

mpl works well with simple latex

```
plt.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$A_{1,1}$',
         fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

which produces a plot as expected.

[image]

unfortunately, putting them together

```
plt.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$\begin{bmatrix}    A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\    A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$',
         fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

produces this trace

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ParseFatalException                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py
>   in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)    2507         try:
>   -> 2508             result = self._expression.parseString(s)    2509         except ParseBaseException as err:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseString(self, instring, parseAll)    1653                 # catch
>   and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack
>   trace
>   -> 1654                 raise exc    1655         else:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseString(self, instring, parseAll)    1643         try:
>   -> 1644             loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )    1645             if parseAll:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3767         if self.expr
>   is not None:
>   -> 3768             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3769         else:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3445             else:
>   -> 3446                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )    3447             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3969         try:
>   -> 3970             return super(ZeroOrMore, self).parseImpl(instring, loc, doActions)    3971         except (ParseException,IndexError):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3898
>   try_not_ender(instring, loc)
>   -> 3899         loc, tokens = self_expr_parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3900         try:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3428         # pre-parsed
>   the string as part of our And pre-parsing
>   -> 3429         loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3430         errorStop = False
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1427                 for fn in self.parseAction:
>   -> 1428                     tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )    1429                     if tokens is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   wrapper(*args)    1071             try:
>   -> 1072                 ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])    1073                 foundArity[0] = True
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py
>   in math_string(self, s, loc, toks)    2575     def math_string(self,
>   s, loc, toks):
>   -> 2576         return self._math_expression.parseString(toks[0][1:-1])    2577
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseString(self, instring, parseAll)    1653                 # catch
>   and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack
>   trace
>   -> 1654                 raise exc    1655         else:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseString(self, instring, parseAll)    1643         try:
>   -> 1644             loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )    1645             if parseAll:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3767         if self.expr
>   is not None:
>   -> 3768             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3769         else:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3898
>   try_not_ender(instring, loc)
>   -> 3899         loc, tokens = self_expr_parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3900         try:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3767         if self.expr
>   is not None:
>   -> 3768             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )    3769         else:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1401                 try:
>   -> 1402                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )    1403                 except IndexError:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)    3580             try:
>   -> 3581                 ret = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )    3582                 return ret
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1550                 try:
>   -> 1551                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1552                 except
>   ParseBaseException as pe:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)    1427                 for fn in self.parseAction:
>   -> 1428                     tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )    1429                     if tokens is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in
>   wrapper(*args)    1071             try:
>   -> 1072                 ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])    1073                 foundArity[0] = True
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py
>   in unknown_symbol(self, s, loc, toks)    2667         c = toks[0]
>   -> 2668         raise ParseFatalException(s, loc, "Unknown symbol: %s" % c)    2669
>
> ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \begin (at char 0), (line:1,
>   col:1)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py
>   in **call**(self, obj)
>       330                 pass
>       331             else:
>   --> 332                 return printer(obj)
>       333             # Finally look for special method names
>       334             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in (fig)
>       235 
>       236     if 'png' in formats:
>   --> 237         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>       238     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
>       239         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
>       119 
>       120     bytes_io = BytesIO()
>   --> 121     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>       122     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
>       123     if fmt == 'svg':
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py
>   in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
>   orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)    2047
>   orientation=orientation,    2048                         dryrun=True,
>   -> 2049                         **kwargs)    2050                     renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer    2051
>   bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
>       508 
>       509         """
>   --> 510         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>       511         renderer = self.get_renderer()
>       512
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in draw(self)
>       400         toolbar = self.toolbar
>       401         try:
>   --> 402             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>       403             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
>       404             # don't forget to call the superclass.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)    1650     1651
>   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
>   -> 1652                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)    1653     1654
>   renderer.close_group('figure')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>   in draw(self, renderer, inframe)    2602
>   renderer.stop_rasterizing()    2603 
>   -> 2604         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)    2605     2606         renderer.close_group('axes')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)
>       707 
>       708         with _wrap_text(self) as textobj:
>   --> 709             bbox, info, descent = textobj._get_layout(renderer)
>       710             trans = textobj.get_transform()
>       711
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py
>   in _get_layout(self, renderer)
>       311                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(clean_line,
>       312                                                         self._fontproperties,
>   --> 313                                                         ismath=ismath)
>       314             else:
>       315                 w, h, d = 0, 0, 0
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
>       212         if ismath:
>       213             ox, oy, width, height, descent, fonts, used_characters = \
>   --> 214                 self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
>       215             return width, height, descent
>       216
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py
>   in parse(self, s, dpi, prop)    3267
>   self.**class**._parser = Parser()    3268 
>   -> 3269         box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)    3270         font_output.set_canvas_size(box.width,
>   box.height, box.depth)    3271         return
>   font_output.get_results(box)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py
>   in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)    2511
>   err.line,    2512                                         " " *
>   (err.column - 1) + "^",
>   -> 2513                                         str(err)]))    2514         self._state_stack = None    2515         self._em_width_cache = {}
>
> ValueError:  \begin{bmatrix}    A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \    A_{2,1} &
>   A_{2,2} \ \end{bmatrix} ^ Unknown symbol: \begin (at char 0),
>   (line:1, col:1)

Comment: You are using mathtext, not latex. In order to be able to use latex in matplotlib you need to enable it via `plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True`. Also mind that backslashes need to be escaped in python, or you need to use raw strings. [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329177/how-to-display-a-matrix-in-the-matplotlib-annotations)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem appears to be three-fold:

1. You need to enable TeX.
2. You need the `amsmath` package to use `bmatrix`.
3. Backslashes warrant special treatment. You can either:

   - Escape backslashes. E.g. your `'\\'` should be `'\\\\'`
   - Use raw strings (*recommended*), where backslashes are not interpreted. E.g. your `'\\'` should be `r'\\'`

The following code solves all three of your problems:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 20
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{{amsmath}}'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$')

plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]