# LaTeX-formulas in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, formula

I'd like to print LaTeX mathmode formulas to images (preferable without saving to hard disk) in Python. I already found matplotlib but it seems one can't dynamically shrink the size of the image to the size of the formula which is what I need.

It would be nice if someone had an example how to accomplish such a thing.

Comment: Have you looked for examples of how to accomplish this?

Rendering LaTex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381741/converting-latex-code-to-images-or-other-displayble-format-with-python

Resizing in Matplotlib:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib

Comment: Already read the second link, but as far as I have seen there isn't a method to get the width of the formula so it doesn't help much. On the other hand I only read till response #1 in the first link before, my fault, and then stoped reading because it only said what I knew before. I therfore missed the sympy answer which seems useful in my case. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LaTeX, use the [`standalone`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package.

Create a LaTeX file with the math in it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle I = \int_0^h y^2\mathrm{d}A$
\end{document}
```

Convert that to pdf:

```
pdflatex eqn.tex
```

Convert the pdf to an image (for example using the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) tools).

```
convert -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch eqn.pdf eqn.png
```

(There are multiple ways of converting LaTeX output to image format. You could also use plain `latex` and `dvipng`.)

This results in:

[image: example]

Running the commands can be done with the `subprocess` module.

**Edit**: Changed to use `\displaystyle`, which looks much nicer than inline math.

Comment: That answer seems much better than that sympy solution (see comments above). Thank you.