# Generating an image of a fraction with python using SymPy

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, latex, sympy

I'm following asmeurer's solution on this thread ([Converting latex code to Images (or other displayble format) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381741/converting-latex-code-to-images-or-other-displayble-format-with-python) and everything worked fine will I tried to display a simple fraction like \frac{2}{3}.

Why am I getting a LaTex abnormally exit error if the LaTex code for the equation is right? It works fine as long as the LaTex code has a single line (I mean, everything is written side by side, once it has to be something written above something else... crashes)

This code works:

```
expr="r'$$\int_0^1 e^x\,dx$$"
preview(expr, viewer='file', filename='test.png', euler=False)
```

and produces this image:

[image: generated PNG]

But this code doesn't:

```
expr="$$\frac{2}{3}$$"
preview(expr, viewer='file', filename='test.png', euler=False)
```

Comment: You probably need a raw string (with an `r` before the string) when your string contains backslashes and curly brackets. So, `expr=r"$$\frac{2}{3}$$"`. See e.g. [What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

Comment: Thank you JohanC!
placing a simple r before the string solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JohanC pointed in his reply to my post: the solution was to place an r before the string. Now the code works like this.

```
expr=r"$$\frac{2}{3}$$"
preview(expr, viewer='file', filename='output.png', euler=False)
```

But... when I try to replace some parts of the expr with a variable... doesn't. But that's another problem.

```
expr=r"$$\frac{+"foo+"}{+"morefoo+"}$$"
```